# Is there a structure on $\mathbb{R}$ with a given cardinality of isomorphisms

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, cardinals

We have, for example
$|\mathrm{Aut} (\mathbb{R})|= |\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}|$
$|\mathrm{Aut} (\mathbb{R,+,0})|= |\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}|$
$|\mathrm{Aut} (\mathbb{R,<})|= |\mathbb{R}|$
$|\mathrm{Aut} (\mathbb{R},<,+,0)|= |\mathbb{R}|$
$|\mathrm{Aut} (\mathbb{R,<,+,\times,0,1})|= 1$

1. If $\kappa \leq |\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}|$ , is there a structure on $\mathbb{R}$  with automorphism group of cardinality $\kappa$ ?
2. Can you give explicit examples for the finite case, $\aleph_0$, $\aleph_1$ and $\aleph_2$.
   I'm especially interested in **common** structures, that occur naturally, but I'd also be interested in any other exotic examples you have.

Comment: Certainly we have lots of freedom in producing *artificial* examples. For instance, for $k$ finite let $G_k$ be the cycle graph on $k$ vertices $\{0,...,k-1\}$ (so there is an edge from $i$ to $j$ iff $j=i+1$ or $i=k-1$ and $j=0$). Then $G_k$ has exactly $k$ automorphisms. Now consider the structure $\mathcal{A}_k$ with domain $\mathbb{R}$, a constant $c_\alpha$ naming $\alpha$ for each real $\alpha\not\in\{0,1,...,k-1\}$, and the structure of $G_k$ on $\{0,1,...,k-1\}$; $\mathcal{A}_k$ has exactly $k$ automorphisms. And replacing $G_k$ with the successor graph on $\mathbb{Z}$ gets $\aleph_0$.

Comment: More generally, for any structure of size $\le 2^{\aleph_0}$ there is a structure with isomorphic automorphism group and domain $\mathbb{R}$.